# PL/SQL Plus script just gives me numbers

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, plsql

I have an PL/SQL Script that I'm trying to run from the command shell with SQLPLUS. However, whenever I go to run it, All I get back is a number and a cursor waiting for some input. When I hit enter, it just increments the number and repeats the process. Here is a dummy query that does the same thing

```
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
    cursor getServerTime IS
        SELECT sysdate as t  from dual;

    myTime getServerTime%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    open getServerTime;

    FETCH getServerTime into myTime;

    dbms_output.put_line(myTime.t);

    close getServerTime;
END;
```

to run this from the command shell I use: `sqlplus me/myPass@myDB @"dummy.sql"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to terminate your script with another line after the END; containing a '/' in the first column, thusly:

```
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
    cursor getServerTime IS
        SELECT sysdate as t  from dual;
    myTime getServerTime%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    open getServerTime;
    FETCH getServerTime into myTime;
    dbms_output.put_line(myTime.t);
    close getServerTime;
END;
/
```

When you create a PL/SQL block via SQL*Plus, the '/' tells SQL*Plus to run everything you've put into the buffer since the last command executed. The incrementing numbers you're getting is SQL*Plus giving you the next line number in your script - it's waiting for you to tell it you're done.